# How to reference app.js in Vue.js with Laravel mix if base URL have sub folder

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My Laravel web application domain is like  `www.mywebsite.com/my-project/public` and I don't want to change.

I installed Vue.js by `npm install && npm run dev`  and try to reference app.js by

```
<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

but I got error  `www.mywebsite.com/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I try to config path in webpack.min.js

```
mix.js('my-project/resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('my-project/resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

but I think it's not way to fix...
Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> You may do so by adding a mix_url configuration option to your application's config/app.php configuration file:

```
'mix_url' => env('MIX_ASSET_URL', null)
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#custom-mix-base-urls)